# Is using 'if (variable == true)' in an if statement any different than 'if (variable)'?

Tags: c#, .net

So I've recently been looking around some code online and have found people using both of the following statements, which has made me curious as to whether or not there is a difference between them.

```
if (true == true) {
   ...
}
```

-

```
if (true) {
   ...
}
```

What I assume happens with the first statement is that it is checked whether or not the fact that true equals true is true (sorry if I am being a bit confusing) and that the second statement simply checks to see if true equals true.

Comment: This depends on the language and if the object can be evaluated.  Having an explicit compare to a value your want it to match does give more control.  `If ( object )`   could return true simply if the object exists and has any value, where `if( object == true )`  means that you only want to enter that condition if `object` is equal to `true` . If you know the object will always be a boolean value or are ok with it evaluating the object as existing with a value, then  `if ( object ) {  }`, will work well for you.

Comment: also some people do it for readability. sometimes to be nice to the guy that comes after me, i will do things explicitly to keep him from having to look for declarations. When i don't want to be nice, i nest function calls 6 deep

Comment: The only different here is that `true == true` gets evaluated as `true`. Likewise if you put `false == false` it evaluates as `true`. Just putting `true` it doesn't need to be evaluated, it's just `true`.

Comment: Who writes `if (true == true)` (literally, just like that)? I've never seen that in any C# code... Anyway, there is a difference if you're using Resharper, which will warn you if you do `true == true`. Zero difference in the generated IL though.

Comment: Or did you really mean to ask "what's the difference between `if (booleanFlag)` and `if (booleanFlag == true)`?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only different here is that `true == true` gets evaluated as `true`. Likewise if you put `false == false` it evaluates as `true`. Just putting `true` it doesn't need to be evaluated, it's just `true`.

Often you'll see people put `if (flag == true)` when they could equally well just put `if (flag)`. The verbose approach is often used to explicitly show what's going on - it perhaps reads a little clearer. I think it reads better when doing the opposite - i.e. `if (!flag)` versus `if (flag == false)`.

I get the feeling that the code you've seen online has just taken a redundant extra step from `if (flag)` to `if (flag == true)` to `if (true == true)` when they know, for whatever reason, that `flag` is always `true`.

Answer (score 3):

**[edit]** For some reason I thought I saw a javascript tag on the question when I first posted this, and so the answer was written for that language. I'll leave it up, because the answer for javascript is not what you might expect; it's still worthwhile to read about.

In the .Net world, there's generally not a functional difference between the two. However, given VB's ability to do implicit runtime conversions, I wouldn't be surprised to learn it's possible to create a contrived example where the conversion does not do what you expect in one circumstance vs the other, especially based on whether the constant expression is first term or the second term of the comparison (which just gives you one more good reason to always use `Option Strict` in VB).

---

Assuming you mean one `true` from each sample is a stand-in for a larger expression, ie:

```
if (expr == true) vs if (expr)
```

**there can be a difference,** based on javascript's [rules of Type Coercion for abstract equality comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). Specifically, note items 5 and 6:

> 5. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
> 6. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Both rules indicate that for an `if (expr == true)` style comparison (or vice versa) the boolean constant is first converted to a number, and then the abstract comparison rules restart. You're basically comparing `expr` to a number (unless `expr` is already a boolean).

However, an `if (expr)` style comparison will try to coerce `expr` directly to a boolean value. It's important here to remember that plenty of things will coerce to a `true` boolean value that will not numerically equate to `true`'s numeric value.

For example:

```
if (3 == true)
{
    alert('3 == true') //this will NOT show
}
else
{
   alert('3 != true') // but this will
}
if (3)
{
    alert('3')  // this WILL also show
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference.  `if (o == true)` performs an equality comparison; `if (o)` invokes the [`true` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx).

To illustrate with a contrived example, suppose we have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public static bool operator true(Foo f) => true;
    public static bool operator false(Foo f) => true;
    public static bool operator == (Foo fb, bool b) => false;
    public static bool operator !=(Foo fb, bool b) => false;
}
```

And suppose we call:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
if (f) Console.WriteLine("A");
if (f == true) Console.WriteLine("B");
```

This segment writes "A" to the console.  The statement `if (f)` invokes the `true` operator, which returns true, so "A" is printed.  The statement `if (f == true)` invokes `Foo.op_Equality(Foo, bool)`, which returns false.

A notable case where `if (o)` and `if (o == true)` differ is where `o` is of type `Nullable<bool>`.  Since `Nullable<bool>` does not have a `true` operator defined, `if (o)` does not compile.  But since `Nullable<T>.Equals(object)` is [defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7b1e4z6(v=vs.110).aspx), `o == true` is itself true if (and only if) `o` has a value and `o.Value` is true.

In the case of a boolean variable, the `true` operator simply returns its value.  As such, there is no practical difference between `if (o)` and `if (o == true)` if `o` is a `bool`.